# Is underscore allowed in case labels?

Tags: c, coding-style, coverity-prevent

In some header file which I can not modify I have the following set of defines:

```
#define FLAG1                      (0x0000_0001)
#define FLAG2                      (0x0000_0002)
...
```

Then, in my code I use them in switch:

```
switch (aaa) {
    case FLAG1:
    ....

    case FLAG2:
    ....
}
```

As a result, Coverity reports on 2 defects per each case label:

```
RW.EXP_RPAREN: 
Event exp_rparen: expected a ")"

RW.CASE_LABEL_CONFLICT:
Event case_label_conflict: case label value has already appeared in 
this switch at line XX
```

What is wrong with these case labels? Does it violate C standards?

Comment: It shouldn't. `case 4*(1+2):` should be valid as well.

Comment: What is the underscore in 0x0000_0001? That's not valid C...

Comment: If you take out the underscores in the hex constants it should be fine.

Comment: @kotlinski  Actually, this underscore is accepted by compiler without any errors/warnings or other negative consequences...

Comment: If you can't get the header fixed, you are going to have to redefine the flag values yourself.  You may as well use an `enum`.  You might write (with slashes for newlines): `#undef FLAG1 / #undef FLAG2 / enum { FLAG1 = 0x0001, FLAG2 = 0x0002 };`.  That undoes the damage from the erroneous header and gives you better debugging (because `enum` symbols are conveyed to the debugger, but preprocessor symbols usually are not).

Comment: If the underscore is accepted, you have a broken compiler - according to the C standard.  Looking at it charitably, you have a compiler with a non-standard extension; don't try it with most compilers.  And your syntax error becomes inexplicable.  The C preprocessor won't object to the underscore; the C compiler should.  **Which compiler** are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. This is our preparatory compiler and now I have an idea to file a CR regarding this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's the underscore that's causing problems.  FWIW, here are the relevant sections from the C language standard (draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

- § 6.4.4.1 Integer Constants: defines the structure for integer constants and shows that `_` is not a valid character for an integer constant;
- § 6.6 Constant Expressions: defines the restrictions on constant expressions;
- § 6.8.4.2 The `switch` statement: defines the restrictions on `case` labels in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are allowed to have parentheses. What you *aren't* allowed to have is a number like `0x0000_0001`.

That's not a valid hex number, you'll probably have to remove the `_` character.

Answer (score 2):

It think it expects the `)` when it finds the `_` which isn't valid in hexadecimal notation.

The compiler should actually complain like this:

```
error: invalid suffix "_0001" on integer constant
```

`case` labels may well contain parentheses:

```
switch(number) {
    // no way to determine operator 
    // precedence without parens here
    case 2*(1+2):
}
```

Comment: That isn't a suffix (according to the 'maximal munch' rule); it is an identifier starting with `_` that is adjacent to the hex constant - and you can't write a number followed by an identifier without an intervening operator.

Comment: Actually, this underscore is accepted by compiler without any errors/warnings or other negative consequences...

Comment: @Jonathan @Pmod Not my gcc, don't. I gave it `0xdead_beef` to "munch" and it complained with the exact same message I posted in the answer... [Lookie here](http://codepad.org/Bc06MUzJ)

Comment: The only reason for that is because it recognizes sometimes that the underscore could be embedded in a constant.  Otherwise, the compiler will tokenize '`(0x0000_0001)`' into `(`, `0x000`, `_0001`, `)`, which is a pair of brackets around a valid number and a valid identifier.  I can't find an option that allows it; I suspct it means there is some other compiler in the world that does allow it.  I have verified that I get the message you show, Linus.